# How Do I Append Coordinates to a List Without Them Getting Overridden in Tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, coordinates, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a vision test app where the user stares at a fixation point in the center of the screen and every few seconds a stimulus will appear and go away. It will do this for a minute. If the user presses spacebar as the stimulus is on the screen, the coordinates of the stimulus are recorded and appended to a list. Eventually I want the program to show exactly where the user can and cannot see based on their keypresses.

The problem is when I try to append the coordinates to a list, the coordinates keep getting overridden. How do I make it so that each coordinate gets appended to the list rather than only the last one?

Here's what I got:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Vision Test")
        self.root.geometry("1920x1080")
        self.root.configure(bg="white")
        self.environment_setup_page()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def environment_setup_page(self):
        heading = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 20), text="Environment Setup", bg="white")
        heading.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.05)
        directions_heading = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="This test is performed with both eyes at the same time. To perform the test correctly, please:", bg="white")
        directions_heading.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.2)
        direction1 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="1. Ensure you are in a quiet environment.", bg="white")
        direction1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3)
        direction2 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="2. Dim the lighting in the room.", bg="white")
        direction2.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.4)
        direction3 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="3. View the chart to determine how far from your screen to sit.", bg="white")
        direction3.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.5)
        direction4 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="4. Please maximize your window so the test fills your entire screen.", bg="white")
        direction4.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.6)
        direction5 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="5. Results may be inaccurate if the test is not performed correctly.", bg="white")
        direction5.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.7)
        table_entry1 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="Screen Size", bg="white")
        table_entry1.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.2)
        table_entry2 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="15\"", bg="white")
        table_entry2.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.3)
        table_entry3 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="17\"", bg="white")
        table_entry3.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.4)
        table_entry4 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="19\"", bg="white")
        table_entry4.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.5)
        table_entry5 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="21\"", bg="white")
        table_entry5.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.6)
        table_entry6 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="23\"", bg="white")
        table_entry6.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.7)
        table_entry7 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="Distance From Screen", bg="white")
        table_entry7.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.2)
        table_entry8 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="13\" / 33cm", bg="white")
        table_entry8.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.3)
        table_entry9 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="14.5\" / 37cm", bg="white")
        table_entry9.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.4)
        table_entry10 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="16\" / 41cm", bg="white")
        table_entry10.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.5)
        table_entry11 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="18\" / 46cm", bg="white")
        table_entry11.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.6)
        table_entry12 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="20\" / 51cm", bg="white")
        table_entry12.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.7)
        continue_button = Button(self.root, text="Continue", width=10, height=2, bg="red", fg="white", borderwidth=0, command=self.instruction_1_page)
        continue_button.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.8)

    def instruction_1_page(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        heading = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 20), text="Instruction 1 - Focus and Respond to Change", bg="white")
        heading.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.05)
        directions_heading = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="During the test you will first respond to a fixation point, which is located in the centre of the testing area.", bg="white")
        directions_heading.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.2)
        direction1 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="1. Keep your eyes focused on the fixation point at all times.", bg="white")
        direction1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3)
        direction2 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="2. Press the space bar when the fixation point changes from a green circle to a yellow triangle.", bg="white")
        direction2.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.4)
        back_button = Button(self.root, text="Back", width=10, height=2, bg="red", fg="white", borderwidth=0, command=self.environment_setup_page)
        back_button.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.5)
        continue_button = Button(self.root, text="Continue", width=10, height=2, bg="red", fg="white", borderwidth=0, command=self.instruction_2_page)
        continue_button.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5)

    def instruction_2_page(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        heading = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 20), text="Instruction 2 - Respond to Stimuli", bg="white")
        heading.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.05)
        directions_heading = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="In addition to responding to the fixation point changes, you will respond when you see a stimulus appear.", bg="white")
        directions_heading.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.2)
        direction1 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="1. Press the space bar every time you see a stimulus appear.", bg="white")
        direction1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3)
        direction2 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="2. Do not search for stimuli; keep both eyes on the fixation point.", bg="white")
        direction2.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.4)
        direction3 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="3. Please Note - You will hear a high-pitched sound when you correctly respond to a stimulus.", bg="white")
        direction3.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.5)
        back_button = Button(self.root, text="Back", width=10, height=2, bg="red", fg="white", borderwidth=0, command=self.instruction_1_page)
        back_button.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.6)
        continue_button = Button(self.root, text="Continue", width=10, height=2, bg="red", fg="white", borderwidth=0, command=self.instruction_summary_page)
        continue_button.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6)

    def instruction_summary_page(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        heading = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 20), text="Take the Test", bg="white")
        heading.place(relx=0.45, rely=0.05)
        directions_heading = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="1. Keep your eyes on the fixation point at all times.", bg="white")
        directions_heading.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.2)
        direction1 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="1. Press the space bar every time you see a stimulus appear.", bg="white")
        direction1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.3)
        direction2 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="2. Press the space bar when the fixation point changes.", bg="white")
        direction2.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.4)
        direction3 = Label(self.root, font=("Arial", 15), text="3. Press the space bar when you see a stimulus.", bg="white")
        direction3.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.5)
        back_button = Button(self.root, text="Back", width=10, height=2, bg="red", fg="white", borderwidth=0, command=self.instruction_2_page)
        back_button.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.6)
        take_the_test_button = Button(self.root, text="Take the Test", width=10, height=2, bg="red", fg="white", borderwidth=0, command=self.vision_test)
        take_the_test_button.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6)

    def vision_test(self):
        self.destroy_widgets()
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, bg="black")
        self.canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.draw_dot(1000, 500, "green")
        self.update_canvas()

    def update_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.after(60000, self.test_results_page)
        self.canvas.after(1000, lambda: self.draw_dot(random.randint(0, 1920), random.randint(0, 1080), "white"))
        self.canvas.after(2000, self.remove_dot)
        self.canvas.after(3000, self.update_canvas)

    def get_results(self, event):
        self.accuracies = []
        inaccuracies = []
        if len(self.canvas.coords(self.dot)) > 0:
            self.accuracies.append(self.canvas.coords(self.dot))
        print(self.accuracies)

    def test_results_page(self):
        print(self.accuracies)
        self.destroy_widgets()
        canvas = Canvas(self.root, bg="white")
        canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        canvas.create_rectangle(self.accuracies[0][0], self.accuracies[0][1], self.accuracies[0][2], self.accuracies[0][3], outline="black", fill="black")

    def draw_dot(self, x, y, color):
        self.dot = self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + 10, y + 10, outline=color, fill=color)
        self.root.bind("<space>", self.get_results)

    def remove_dot(self):
        self.canvas.delete(self.dot)

    def destroy_widgets(self):
        for widgets in self.root.winfo_children():
            widgets.destroy()

win = Window()
```

The problem lies in the get_results() function:

```py
def get_results(self, event):
        self.accuracies = []
        inaccuracies = []
        if len(self.canvas.coords(self.dot)) > 0:
            self.accuracies.append(self.canvas.coords(self.dot))
        print(self.accuracies)

    def test_results_page(self):
        print(self.accuracies)
        self.destroy_widgets()
        canvas = Canvas(self.root, bg="white")
        canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        canvas.create_rectangle(self.accuracies[0][0], self.accuracies[0][1], self.accuracies[0][2], self.accuracies[0][3], outline="black", fill="black")

    def draw_dot(self, x, y, color):
        self.dot = self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + 10, y + 10, outline=color, fill=color)
        self.root.bind("<space>", self.get_results)
```

Comment: Every time `get_results()` is called, you explicitly set `self.accuracies` to an empty list.  You need to do that initialization *once*, at the start of the process.

Comment: See [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).